# Spring Boot 2.4.1 trying to initialise jetty even when not specified

Tags: spring, spring-boot

As I have read, spring-boot by default uses an embedded Tomcat server but in my case its trying to bring up jetty server even when not specified. And in doing so, throwing exception as I have not included jetty dependencies. By looking at exception, it looks like it started with EmbeddedTomcat then for some reason switched to jetty by trying to wire bean 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer'.

`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer`

Following are the spring-boot dependencies I have in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also import the EmbeddedTomcat configuration directly. Has the same effect as declaring TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory directly and should there be any change with it you won't need to update anything.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat.class)
```

... your configuration class